# Length buffer around polyline

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps

I'm not very good at mathematics, so I got a problem. I have a route from one, to another distination. Some time I was trying to apply a colored plot aroud the route in fixed length. But I cant get a nice rounded corners and my lack of math is making me a lot of truble.

**Now I got this**
[image]

**And the code**

```
        var r = [];
        var bla = result.routes[0].overview_path;
        for(i in result.routes[0].overview_path) {
            r.push(new google.maps.LatLng(bla[i].lat()+z, bla[i].lng()-z));
        }
        bla.reverse();
        for(x in bla) {
            r.push(new google.maps.LatLng(bla[x].lat()-z, bla[x].lng()+z));
        }

        var kelias = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: result.routes[0].overview_path,
            strokeColor: "#00000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });

        kelias.setMap(MAP);

        fonas = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: r,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });

        fonas.setMap(MAP);
```

*I just want to ask for some information directions OR maybe some of you already have made this functionality and have some functions*

Working [demo here](http://gis5.com/pois_along_route/gm_pois_along_route.php). Somehow i need to get same result of drawing that.

**SOLUTIONS**

- [Buffered polyline using JSTS lib.](https://coderwall.com/p/zb_zdw/buffered-polyline)
- [ArcGIS server solution](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/buffer-polyline-.htm)

Comment: Some remarks on the link you posted (working demo). They calculate the polyline on the server and then get them with ajax before drawing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this stack in SO [Path stroke algorithm (convert to triangles/quads) or other suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025043/path-stroke-algorithm-convert-to-triangles-quads-or-other-suggestions) where there is a similar question, just for C++.

The answer is a algorithm in [this PDF](https://keithp.com/~keithp/talks/cairo2003.pdf) on page 3 (the CONVOLVE algorithm).

If you perhaps could make a working example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), we could be able to program a solution in there.

-- edit

After some time of analysing the script in the link you provided for the [life demo](http://gis5.com/pois_along_route/gm_pois_along_route.php), I found, that the polyline is not calculated in javascript, but is calculated on the server and returned with a AJAX call to some PERL programme.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just draw another polyline on the same path as the first one, with a larger stroke?  It doesn't give you exactly the same results, i.e. a polygon with a border color different from its fill color, but the overall effect is very similar.

```
// first, black line
var kelias = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: result.routes[0].overview_path,
            strokeColor: "#000000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });

// second, translucent red line
var kelias2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: result.routes[0].overview_path,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 40,
            map: MAP
        });
```

**Update:** You're adding and subtracting 'z' from both the latitude and longitude of the points along your path.  Given that latitude runs from +90 to -90, but longitude runs from +180 to -180, I think you maybe need different values for each.

Comment: Actualy no. Becouse I will use same formula for geting records in that plot. Im looking for more optimal way for that.

Comment: Added another suggestion to my answer

Comment: Z is just vizualisation. Its not actual value.

Comment: This seems to be a performant solution without calculating the outline. I would go for this, if the colors I wanted allow for it

Comment: But there is limits for stroke Weight.

Comment: strokeWeight is a width in pixels - what limits are there?

Comment: strokeWeight is limited to 33